# Call one step from within another, Spinach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gherkin, spinach

I recall there being a way to execute a step from within another step using spinach.

As I recall, such a step would appear similar to the following:

```
...
step "I create a patient as a facility's administrator" do
  %Q{ Given I am a facility's administrator }
  %Q{ Given I create a patient }
end
...
```

Found [.execute(step)](http://rubydoc.info/github/codegram/spinach/master/Spinach/DSL/InstanceMethods%3aexecute) but haven't had any luck getting at a Step object to send as argument.  How can I execute steps from within another step?  Help is appreciated.

Comment: can find desired step in ObjectSpace, but surely spinach offers a more direct way to call & execute a step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute` is an internal method that shouldn't be used from a feature. If you want to execute a step from another step *you do have to* underscore it. Spinach maintainers suggest extracting the logic in "I am a facility's administrator" and "I create a patient" step to another method, and calling this very method from other steps.

```
step "I create a patient as a facility's administrator" do
  log_as_facility_admin
  create_patient
end

def log_as_facility_admin
  # something
end

def create_patient
  # something
end
```

source: https://github.com/codegram/spinach/issues/132